# How to use one APIGateway to multiple lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I have two `lambda` functions .

Now I want to use one api for these two.

Then my code is like this

```ts
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'ServerlessRestApi', {
    restApiName: `AWSCDKTest-${systemEnv}`,
    cloudWatchRole: false
});

api.root.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(helloLambda));
api.root.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(happyLambda));
```

Howeber it says `GET` is doubled.

So I made two API

```ts
const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'ServerlessRestApi_hello', {
    restApiName: `AWSCDK-Viral-${systemEnv}`,
    cloudWatchRole: false
});
api.root.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(helloLambda));

const api2 = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'ServerlessRestApi_happy', { cloudWatchRole: false });
api2.root.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(happyLambda));
```

It works, but it makes two API.

What is the best practice to use one API for two lambda??

Comment: can you post exact error message?

Comment: I have never used CDK before but I assume it has the same structure as the other provisioning methods. So instead of adding method directly to the root resource, you should create 2 resources (paths) and then add the method GET to each resource, example https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.Resource.html.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```js
// ./helloService.helloLambda.js file sample
export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {},
    body: 'helloLambda',
  };
};
// ./helloService.happyLambda.js file sample
export const handler = async (event, context) => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {},
    body: 'happyLambda',
  };
};

// .helloService file sample
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { NodejsFunction } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda-nodejs';
import * as apigateway from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';
export class HelloService extends Construct {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    const helloLambdaFunction = new NodejsFunction(this, 'helloLambda');
    const happyLambdaFunction = new NodejsFunction(this, 'happyLambda');

    const api = new apigateway.RestApi(this, 'hello-api', {
      description: 'This service is Happy.',
    });

    const helloLambdaPath = api.root.addResource('helloLambda'); 
    // path name https://{createdId}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/prod/helloLambda

    helloLambdaPath.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(helloLambdaFunction));

    const happyLambdaPath = api.root.addResource('happyLambda'); 
    // path name https://{createdId}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/prod/happyLambda

    happyLambdaPath.addMethod('GET', new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(happyLambdaFunction));
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

API root:
`GET "https://example_api_endpoint/"` invokes `helloLambda` then inside this lambda function call the AWS-SDK lambda API method `invoke()` to trigger the execution of `happyLambda` within the first invocation in sequence. Otherwise, you cannot have two lambda functions for a single API resource. Further reading: AWS Lambda Fanout pattern.

Answer (score 0):

One lambda cannot be linked to exact same API path + Http verb. Here are some alternatives -

a) have different api paths, each calling different lambda

b) have one lambda triggered by API gateway, which triggers other lambda that you need (within it's code)

c) have the lambda integration to the endpoint that sends a message to SNS, and have multiple lambda subscribe to the SNS via SQS.

Answer (score 0):

try this

this.api = new RestApi(this, 'ServerlessRestApi', {
restApiName: "myapi",
cloudWatchRole: false
});

this.api.root.addResource(resource).addMethod('GET', new LambdaIntegration(func));

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can set the API Gateway to trigger a step function which can have multiple Lambdas